# How to show only years on x axis of pandas histogram?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas histogram that shows the frequency that specific years show up in a dataframe. The x axis contains 2006.0, 2006.5, 2007.0, 2007.5, etc.

However I want my histogram x axis to only have 2006, 2007, etc. This will make my histogram clearer, especially since in my df I only have values for particular years in their integer form, not 2006.5, 2007.4, etc.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: If you want to convert float to int , use df.columnname.astype(int)

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do it.

1) if you just want to change the display format, by using the {:,.0f} format to explicitly display (rounded) floating point values with no decimal numbers:

`pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.0f}'.format`

2) if you want to convert it to int : `df.col = df.col.astype(int)`

Comment: Hi @itstoocold if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.